# Gap between overlaying views in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering how I can get a gap between overlaying views in swift. This is really hard for me to explain so I added a couple images to explain what I'm talking about [This is the effect in iMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbL3S.jpg) [The same effect in Facebook Messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QAGw.jpg) [And again in facebook messenger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QBhf.jpg). I am talking about the little gap of space in between the view that says the number of minutes and the profile image (in the 3rd image). I was wondering how I could achieve the same thing in Swift because I'd like to integrate this into my app. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this many ways.

One of the way, I am posting.

One View, `UIView`, that should be Square. Inside that, One `UIImageView` and One `SmallView`

**Constraints as follows:**

OuterView: width & height be 120, top 50, and Center Horizontally

ImageView = { 4,4,4,4 },

SmallView = right and bottom as 0, width and height be 40 [Square]

PlusSignImgVw = { 4,4,4,4 }

**Like below:**

[image]

**Coding:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    imageVw.layer.cornerRadius = imageVw.frame.size.width / 2

    smallSquareView.layer.cornerRadius = smallSquareView.frame.size.width / 2
    smallSquareView.clipsToBounds = true

    plusSign.layer.cornerRadius = plusSign.frame.size.width / 2
    plusSign.clipsToBounds = true

}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, not obvious at first, but not too difficult either.

For the round images, try this:

```
customView.layer.cornerRadius = customView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
customView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
```

For the rectangular image with round corners, first line will calculate the .cornerRadius based on height (or you can actually do it for all the cases, and it would also work):

```
customView.layer.cornerRadius = customView.bounds.size.width / 2.0
```

Just replace `customView` with `yourCustomViewName` and write those 3 lines for each view. That should do the job.

Comment: this also makes sense. Thanks!